# organization document management with oneDrive

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

What would be best in sharing documents across an organization?

1. OneDrive
   or
2. SharePoint

I think I would like the following attributes:

- Scripting to eliminate redundancy and auto updates of files
- Only specific clients can view the files

And what security concerns should I look out for.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, itemise your requirements and ask what you are looking for.